# WooCommerce - change order status automatically without having received payement

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have a B2B shop with WooCommerce which just takes orders without making any payments in the shop because these orders are being submitted to our ERP system (which will send the invoice once the order is processed there). Actually there is no payment gateway added to the shop. We have bank transfer after receiving the invoice as the only payment method active in the shop.

Consequently we want/need to have the status of an order changed automatically to PROCESSING, once an order is placed.

We tried following code which, however, has no effect on the order status.

Can anyone please help out - thanks!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if( $order->get_status() == 'wc-pending' )
        $order->update_status( 'wc-processing' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After longer search, I found a function that works for us:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_process_payment_order_status', 'change_bacs_payment_order_status', 10, 2 ); 
function change_bacs_payment_order_status( $order_status, $order ) {
    return 'processing';
}
```